# I have an inequality which is giving me the correct answer, except that the sign is opposite to what it should be, any help?

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, logarithms, geometric-series

I'm looking at a geometric series that looks like

$A_n = \sum_{k=0}^{n}A_0x^k$ where $A_0$ is a constant.

I'm looking to find an $n$ where my error between two terms is less than a certain value $E$ such that

$A_n - A_{n-1} \le E$.

Now,

$A_n - A_{n-1} = A_0x^n$

Therefore I need

$A_0x^n \le E$,

which I can rewrite as

$\ln{A_0} +n\ln{x} \le \ln{E}$

$n \le \frac{\ln{E/A_0}}{\ln{x}}$

Which gives me what I need (i.e. the correct $n$ for the error I expect), except that it should be that $n$ is greater than this and not less than. Can anyone see what I've missed? Perhaps more caffeine is needed?

Many thanks.

Comment: $\ln{x}$ is negative, isn’t it?

Comment: I think you mistyped the first formula, and it should read $A_n = \sum_{k = 0}^n A_0x^k$ is that correct?

Comment: Thanks, I've just looked at it and $x \le 1$, writing the series by hand I can see that greater $n$ is giving me lower error, I just can't get the inequality correct.

Comment: @Vincent You're correct sorry

Comment: Ok, good, then please edit the question!

Comment: Not counting the meaningless reuse of the index $n$, the sum equals  $$\frac{A_0}{1-x}$$ which is a constant. Please fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sign is correct, with $x > 1$ and $A_0 > 1$, the error term $A_0x^n$ grows with $n$. Therefore if you want the error term to be **lower than** a constant, you need $n$ to be **small**

Now if you take $x<1$, I guess your interest, than the error term decreases with $n$, and $ln(x)<0$, therefore when dividing by $ln(x)$ you have to switch sign.

$$ \ln A_0 + n\ln x \leq \ln E \Rightarrow
\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
n \leq \frac{\ln E/A_0}{\ln x} & \text{ if } x>1\\
n \geq \frac{\ln E/A_0}{\ln x} & \text{ if } x<1\\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

Comment: Perfect! Thank you Thomas

Answer (score 1):

$\ln(x)$ is negative as $x < 1$. So when you divide by $\ln(x)$ you have to flip the sign on the inequality.